# Getting values with regex grouping construct in C#

Tags: c#, regex

Hi everyone I'm quite new to regular expressions and I'm trying to get srcs values out of img tags in html webpages, so I've made this regular expression: `@"<img.*src *=*([\x22\x27])(?<path>.+)(\1).*/>"`
But when I try to get the value frome the group "path" with this sample tag:
`<img src='kkkkkk' class='icon' alt='' />`
I get `kkkkkk' class='icon' alt='` instead of just `kkkkkk`. I just can't figure it out.
Here is the code I'm using to exctract and print the data:

```
Regex SrcRegex = new Regex(@"<img.*src *=*([\x22\x27])(?<path>.+)(\1).*/>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

string TestTag = "<img src='kkkkkk' class='icon' alt='' />";

MatchCollection MatchedString = SrcRegex.Matches(ReadIn);

foreach (Match M in MatchedString)
        Console.WriteLine(M.Groups["path"].Value);
```

Thanks guys for the attention and excuse me for my English.

Comment: One of the most popular answers of SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: if you want to parse HTML, you are better off going with the HTMLAgilityPack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with html, it is better to use an html parser instead of regex. For example using [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(htmlstring);

var imgUrls = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
                .Select(img => img.Attributes["src"].Value)
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer in regex terms, the problem is simply that you're using a greedy quantifier in `(?<path>.+)`, so it matches to the *last* quote, not the *next* one, as you intend. Just make it non-greedy:

```
Regex SrcRegex = new Regex(@"<img.*src *= *([\x22\x27])(?<path>.+?)(\1).*/>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

BTW, I added a space after the **=**, because I take it that's what you intended. You want to require the **=**, and optionally match spaces after it, right? The way you had it would match zero or more **=** signs, with no spaces allowed between the **=** and the opening quote.